# How to connect to Exchange Server 2013 via PHP?

Tags: php, api, outlook, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to figure out a way was I can connect to Exchange Server 2013 where I can read/send email. Also, Add/view event calendar event.

Is there a PHP API that will allow me to access the information?

Comment: try this library:
https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews

and be sure to check this issue:
https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues/271

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Exchange Web Services. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.